# How to show web page in layered windows using c#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

My requirement is to create TV STB like functionality  where we can see TV Menu on top of the video being played in the background..I am using  two layered windows one to show the frame of the video captured  and another to show the web page on it(like a ticker).. I need to show web page on the image as an overlapped transparent window. I am able to create a layered window after doing some research and can even make those windows transparent using alpha blending using these links [Link1](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/perpxalpha_sharp.aspx), [Link2](http://www.codeproject.com/kb/gdi/pxalphablend.aspx) and [link3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632599.aspx#layered) ..However I cannot find any way to show a web page or web content  in the layered window
Do i need to create any child window for showing web page.. If so how can this be created in windows 7..I really need to achieve this ..Any suggestions that can point me in the right direction will be really appreciated.

Comment: To show a web page in a WinForms form, you can use the [WebBrowser control](http://www.dotnetperls.com/webbrowser). Does this solve your problem...?

Comment: @Richard Everett: Actually I working on layered windows ..they don't use any controls..as spcified

Comment: Is this a mandatory requirement? If you need translucent windows you can achieve this in WinForms by setting the [Opacity property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.opacity(v=vs.110).aspx) accordingly. Slightly confused by your requirements.

Comment: Actually my requirement is to render web page on an image ..I chose to achieve this by using layered windows as they always stay on top of other windows ..Using layered windows can i render web page by any technique..?????????

Comment: Where are you getting the web page from?
If you need to display an image behind the content of the page you could use a WinForms form and WebBrowser control to display the page, but intercept the HTML and use the [HTML Agility Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to set the [`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) CSS value of the body to the image you want to display.

Comment: @Richard: Ok..Actually My app is supposed to capture the frames of a video coming over hdmi  and then do the frame processing and if the required frame is found render the web page on that frame ...I am able to capture the video frames using a capture card now I want o render web page on that frame much like TV STB functionality where we can see the TV menu on top of the video being played in the background..and in windows it can be achieved through layered windows..thats why i ma using layered windows..i think this might give you as clearer idea of my requirement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74713/discussion-between-g-droid-and-richard-everett).